# how do you scrape an instagram post?

Tags: python, selenium, bots

I have been working on a bot that simply opens Instagram, searches a profile leaves a comment on the latest post. For example I'm using this code,

```
def profile_click(browser):
    sleep(3)
    profile_click = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/nav/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/a/div")
    profile_click.click()
```

This simply clicks on the profile and it works great. However once I'm in the profile and I try to click on the latest post I run into problems. The post does not get clicked on. This is the code I'm using:

```
def post_click(browser):
    sleep(3)
    post_click = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div[3]/article/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/a")
    post_click.click()
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this is and how I can fix it?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: sleep for more than 3 seonds, and check whether its working or not, cuz webpage loads faster than the image contents and script tag sometimes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this **xpath** to click on first post:

```
(//span[text()='Posts']/ancestor::div[@role='tablist']/following-sibling::div/descendant::a[@href])[1]/..
```

wrap it like this :

```
def post_click(browser):
    sleep(3)
    post_click = browser.find_element_by_xpath("(//span[text()='Posts']/ancestor::div[@role='tablist']/following-sibling::div/descendant::a[@href])[1]/..")
    post_click.click()
```